# Strict Standards: Non-static method Crypt_RSA_MathLoader::loadWrapper() should not be called statically

Tags: php, rsa, pear

after updating php to 5.5 I get this error:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Crypt_RSA_MathLoader::loadWrapper() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Crypt/RSA.php on line 195 
Strict Standards: Non-static method Crypt_RSA_MathLoader::loadWrapper() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Crypt/RSA/MathLoader.php on line 97
```

I'm using pear's Crypt_RSA. Thanks.

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward

Comment: Default: $obj = &Crypt_RSA_MathLoader::loadWrapper($wrapper_name); Changed: $obj = (new Crypt_RSA_MathLoader)->loadWrapper($wrapper_name); Didn't help.

Comment: This is probably on more than one line, find any other usages and change them as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pear's Crypt_RSA has been deprecated by phpseclib's Crypt_RSA:

http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RSA/redirected

you should consider updating.